# getting menuitems clicked menuitem and its neighbours

Tags: c#, menustrip

i want to do the following:
when a certain menuitem is being clicked, this one should become checked and the ones lying directly next to it should become unchecked.. I tried to solve the first part of this problem as follows:

```
private void runningToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;
        mi.Checked = true;//causes nullpointer exception

        menuStrip1.Items[mi.index+1].Checked=false;
        menuStrip1.Items[mi.index-1].Checked=false;
    }
```

also this "solution" causes a nullpointer exception..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sender` value is not a `MenuItem`. That's why you ge the exception. You should instead cast to to `ToolStripItem` see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.click(v=vs.110).aspx)

However since `ToolStripItem` doesn't have the `Checked` property you may want to cast it to `ToolStripMenuItem` which derives from `ToolStripItem`.

```
var mi = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
if (mi == null)
{
   return; // not a menu item
}

// do your stuff here
```

Comment: when I cast it to toolstripItem, there is no checked-property?

Comment: You can try casting it to `ToolStripMenuItem` which derives from `ToolStripItem` and has the `Checked` property.